# Error with search and activating Features with new web application Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, search

I have got some web application and the search works well and good for those web applications.its a Sharepoint 2013
The web application has been added to the content source "Local SharePoint sites"
I created another new web application and i can't get to search.Anytime I do a search i get the error in the ULS log

> The start address "" cannot be crawled.  Context: Application
>   'Search_Service_Application',

when i go to the site and do  search i get error and also when i try and activate any feature:

> An error occurred while processing the request on the server. The
>   status code returned from the server was: 0

Any ideas what to check and what to test?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: After you created the web application did you provision a top level site collection? There needs to be content present and a site for the crawler to work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you given the search crawler account read access through a User Policy on the new web application? (Compare the User Policies on your two web applications)

This is crucial in order to for the crawler to be able to index all content in the web application.

Guide, and more information on Technet:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff608071.aspx

Comment: Thanks Robert.I have gone through the user policy and it seems all fine.Also getting error An error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 0 when trying to activate features.Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have the ability to restart the server? Seems one of the services on it might be down?